# Regular Expression for Validating the Completeness of a CSV

Tags: java, regex, csv, pattern-matching, match

I'm using a Workflow Automation tool (Built with Java) that allows for the Input of a CSV file. The CSV will be manually created and based on which columns are populated, certain actions will be performed by the workflow. Therefore, I need to match the string (one CSV row at a time) only when the following conditions are NOT found:

- Comma at the Start of the String [Indicates 1st Value is missing]
- Comma space Comma [Indicates a Middle Value is missing]
- Comma at the End of the String [Indicates Last Value is Missing]

Consider the following Input Text to Match

```
HMSS TN PUPIL EDITION LV 5,HMHSS Ohio PE LV 5-6 Making A New Nation, HMH SCIFSN TN SE G6 2019, CA IMPUSHGGROCONFG8SUBBXCNTLBL, "R180 NG LBOOK TG STG B NAT""L", HMH BIEN DIT TE LV1A/18/1 2018, DTM NOW TE M&D, MD GOMATH SP SE INACTV WKTXT ACC7 2014*, "0158009673, 0158009681, 015800969X, 0158009703"
```

Input Text Rules:
Cannot Start with a Space, Cannot End with a Space

This should not Match - 1st Value is missing:

```
,HMHSS Ohio PE LV 5-6 Making A New Nation, HMH SCIFSN TN SE G6 2019, CA IMPUSHGGROCONFG8SUBBXCNTLBL, "R180 NG LBOOK TG STG B NAT""L", HMH BIEN DIT TE LV1A/18/1 2018, DTM NOW TE M&D, MD GOMATH SP SE INACTV WKTXT ACC7 2014*, "0158009673, 0158009681, 015800969X, 0158009703"
```

This should not Match - Middle Value is missing:

```
HMHSS Ohio PE LV 5-6 Making A New Nation, , HMH SCIFSN TN SE G6 2019, CA IMPUSHGGROCONFG8SUBBXCNTLBL, "R180 NG LBOOK TG STG B NAT""L", HMH BIEN DIT TE LV1A/18/1 2018, DTM NOW TE M&D, MD GOMATH SP SE INACTV WKTXT ACC7 2014*, "0158009673, 0158009681, 015800969X, 0158009703"
```

This should not Match - Last Value is Missing:

```
HMHSS Ohio PE LV 5-6 Making A New Nation, HMH SCIFSN TN SE G6 2019, CA IMPUSHGGROCONFG8SUBBXCNTLBL, "R180 NG LBOOK TG STG B NAT""L", HMH BIEN DIT TE LV1A/18/1 2018, DTM NOW TE M&D, MD GOMATH SP SE INACTV WKTXT ACC7 2014*, "0158009673, 0158009681, 015800969X, 0158009703",
```

**The Expressions I've Tried**:

```
^(("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*)(,("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*))*)$
```

> Matches the Entire String

---

```
[-\w\s"/&*]+(,[-\w\s"/&*]+)*
```

> The Closest I've come. Does not catch the "Comma space Comma". 
>   And I need to Consider the entire Input String as a Whole.

Thank you so much for reading and your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -En "/^[^\s,][^,]*[^\s,](,[^\s,][^,]*[^\s,])*$/p"
```

Expect:

- start "^"
- something other than white space or comma "[^\s,]
- something other than comma "[^,]"
- possibly many "*"
- something other than white space or comma  "[^\s,]"
  (not sure about this one being a rule, remove if not)
- the following "("

  - a comma ","
  - like see above
- until here ")"
- several times if you like "*"
- the end "$"

If you want to use the entire string, enclose it in another pair of "()" and use "\1".
I show a demonstrator in sed.
I can translate to perl or egrep flavor of regexes, but lack experience in regex flavors used by java.